# Android PreferenceFragment loaded with no errors but screen is blank

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-support-design

I am trying to implement a PreferenceFragment to be loaded from an AppCompatActivity (Or a regular Activity) and I seem to have made it get into the preference fragment's onCreate method, but the screen shows up blank. Below is an image:

[image]

I have a feeling that the fragment is loading behind the layout, but I have no idea how to check this, since I get similar behaviour even if I run it on an empty Activity layout with a single FrameLayout. I'm trying to display a settings page from within my Main using onOptionSelected().

I've been stuck on this for like a week and none of the answers I find are helping, any help would be much much appreciated!

Here is my code for the Activity:

```
public class genericActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(Main.appTAG, "onCreate: settings activity");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_generic);
    // IF intent message == settings
    final Fragment settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentParent, settingsFragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
            new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onBackStackChanged() {
                    getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .remove(settingsFragment)
                            .commit();
                }
            });

  }

}
```

The Layout for the Activity, ie activity_generic.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.thesis.deefunkt.thesispractise.genericActivity">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />



</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentParent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list">

    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I do not need the compatibility features really, since all this screen does is settings, but kept it for the consistent look.

My code for SettingsFragment is as follows:

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
    Log.d(Main.appTAG, "onCreate: SettingsFragment ");
}

}
```

While this is running, I have a bunch of log entries which I dont know how to interpret:

```
D/com.deefunkt.UsbComms: onCreate: settings activity
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor mIsFloating : false
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* installDecor flags : -2139029248
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
D/Activity: performCreate Call Injection manager
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x2580 a=-1}
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x8 a=-1}
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x1 a=-1}
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x0 a=-1}


D/com.deefunkt.UsbComms: onCreate: SettingsFragment 
I/InjectionManager: dispatchPreferences > Target : com.thesis.deefunkt.thesispractise.SettingsFragment
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.thesis.deefunkt.thesispractise.SettingsFragment isFragment :true
I/InjectionManager: dispatchOnViewCreated > Target : com.thesis.deefunkt.thesispractise.genericActivity isFragment :false
D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null
D/PhoneWindow: *FMB* isFloatingMenuEnabled return false
D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered! 
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1440x2560]-format:1
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x7f65c06600 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7f74cff540
```

As you can see, the onCreate method inside the fragment gets called, but I dont know what to do with this log data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a FrameLayout to inflate the Fragment, not the root layout of the Activity.  Also, use a [PreferenceFragmentCompat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html) since you're using an AppCompatActivity

Comment: Sorry, are you saying that rather than using LinearLayout, I should use FrameLayout (but within activity_generic.xml), or should I create a new xml file with a single FrameLayout inside it? I thought since we have defined the preference object holding xml file thats the layout that the fragment uses and we just pass it a container to put it in?

Comment: You're going to have to refactor your code... If you're using Fragments then no content should go in the Activity layout, instead of the content put a FrameLayout  where the Fragments are inflated http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#AddAtRuntime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after spending all this time on this, I finally managed to fix the bug but I dont know why. My best guess is that

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.fragmentParent, settingsFragment)

/*Adding to the backStack here and then setting a backStack Listener
 *on the next step made it add the fragment then immediately take it     
 *off, giving my empty activity layout.*/

        .addToBackStack(null)
        .commit();
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(
        new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                getFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .remove(settingsFragment)
                        .commit();
            }
        });
```

I removed the call to addToBackStack() and commented out the backStack listener, since I realized I don't need to remove the fragment after the activity loads with it and only really care about reusing the activity for multiple fragments.